# React-Native iOS: How to determine that the Switch Control accessibility feature is enabled?

Tags: ios, react-native, accessibility, voiceover

I have a React-Native application.
I made an alternative view for one screen for the case when VoiceOver accessibility feature is enabled. I made this using AccessibilityInfo. But I can't figure out how to check if Switch Control accessibility feature is enabled. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: It's `UIAccessibility.isSwitchControlRunning` for **Swift**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Native Module according to this doc:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios

```
#import "RNAccessibilityManager.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RNAccessibilityManager ()
@end

@implementation RNAccessibilityManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getCurrentSwitchControlState:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    callback(@[@(UIAccessibilityIsSwitchControlRunning())]);
}

@end
```

Linked it manually and used like this:

```
import RNAccessibilityManager from 'react-native-accessibility-manager'

RNAccessibilityManager.getCurrentSwitchControlState((isEnabled) => {
  this.setState({
    switchControlEnabled: isEnabled,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check it this way:

```
AccessibilityInfo.fetch().then((isEnabled) => {
  this.setState({
    screenReaderEnabled: isEnabled,
  });
});
```

Read the docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibilityinfo

Comment: I've edited the title. I'm asking about Switch Control accessibility feature, not Switch component.

Comment: I'm not sure if Screen Reader is this same as Switch control But looks like it's only available api.

Comment: Thanks but AccessibilityInfo can't help to determine the Switch Control feature state. "Screen Reader" is VoiceOver for iOS and TalkBack for Android.

Comment: From what i can see it's missing feature in React Native. Please add Your own answer here if You will find out something!